# Quelle serait une façon plus claire de rendre l’idée exprimée dans la phrase citée ci-après?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Cela m’est arrivé (le bris de mon pare-brise) alors que je franchissais un pont.

Serait-il préférable que je laisse tomber «alors que » pour le remplacer par un terme moins lourd comme « en »: Cela m’est arrivé en franchissant un pont.

Je suis dans l’attente de vos propositions.

Merci

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui te fait penser que la phrase n'est (peut-être) pas suffisamment claire ? Ou estimes-tu seulement qu'elle est trop lourde ?

Comment: À plus forte raison qu’elle est trop lourde, souvent, quand j’emploie cette locution conjonctive on me reproche de m’exprimer de manière ampoulée, certains prétendent même que je suis maniéré, que je manque de naturel...

Comment: Ce que je cherche avant tout, en étant sur cette plateforme, c’est de rendre mon expression la plus simple et la plus concise qu’il me le sera possible.

Comment: J'éviterais d'employer le participe présent quoi qu'il en soit. Ca me donne l'impression que le bris du pare-brise est dû à la traversée du pont... mais peut-être est-ce juste mon interprétation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La phrase est très claire mais effectivement, on peut lui reprocher d'avoir un style trop recherché : ***cela***, ***alors que*** temporel et ***franchir*** sont tous trois soutenus.

Deux propositions:

> Ça m’est arrivé pendant que je traversais un pont.

> C'est arrivé au moment où je passais sur (ou sous?) un pont.

Answer (score 0):

Comme dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/45254/26366) mais avec la substitution. La phrase en question donne l'impression qu'on aurait parlé du fait que le pare-brise se soit brisé indépendamment de la précision (*Mon pare-brise s'est brisé. Cela m'est...*), d'où le besoin d'y référer. On peut faire d'une pierre deux coups si le but est de rendre l'expression « la plus simple et la plus concise [...] possible » :

> Mon pare-brise s'est brisé pendant que je passais sur le pont.
> ...quand j'étais/je roulais sur le pont.